# Execution speed of references vs pointers

Tags: pointers, compiler-construction, reference, jit, vm-implementation

I recently read a discussion regarding whether managed languages are slower (or faster) than native languages (specifically C# vs C++). One person that contributed to the discussion said that the JIT compilers of managed languages would be able to make optimizations regarding references that simply isn't possible in languages that use pointers.

What I'd like to know is what kind of optimizations that are possible on references and not on pointers?

Note that the discussion was about execution speed, not memory usage.

Comment: Well, if you aren't managing memory properly that can certainly hurt execution speed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are some benefits of [JIT compilation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Just-in-time_compilation) mentioned in Wikipedia:

> JIT code generally offers far better performance than interpreters. In addition, it can in some or many cases offer better performance than static compilation, as many optimizations are only feasible at run-time:
>
> 1. The compilation can be optimized to the targeted CPU and the operating system model where the application runs. For example JIT can choose SSE2 CPU instructions when it detects that the CPU supports them. With a static compiler one must write two versions of the code, possibly using inline assembly.
> 2. The system is able to collect statistics about how the program is actually running in the environment it is in, and it can rearrange and recompile for optimum performance. However, some static compilers can also take profile information as input.
> 3. The system can do global code optimizations (e.g. inlining of library functions) without losing the advantages of dynamic linking and without the overheads inherent to static compilers and linkers. Specifically, when doing global inline substitutions, a static compiler must insert run-time checks and ensure that a virtual call would occur if the actual class of the object overrides the inlined method.
> 4. Although this is possible with statically compiled garbage collected languages, a bytecode system can more easily rearrange memory for better cache utilization.

I can't think of something related directly to the use of references instead of pointers.

Comment: One concrete big project proof was made with IronPython vs CPython. The latest versions of IronPython beat CPython in every benchmark, with a small or big margin, while retaining 100% compatbility. That's with a several years of optimisations of CPython and a young IronPython project.

Comment: You haven't answered the question... "What I'd like to know is what kind of optimizations that are possible on references and not on pointers?"...

Comment: I think the point of the question might be based on assumptions about how references and pointers are used in actual practice (is your reference to a specific object? is your pointer merely to void?) as opposded to anything intrinsic to the way they work.

Answer (score 10):

In C++ there are two advantages of references related to optimization aspects:

1. A reference is constant (refers to the same variable for its whole lifetime)

   Because of this it is easier for the compiler to infer which names refer to the same underlying variables - thus creating optimization opportunities. There is no guarantee that the compiler will do better with references, but it might...
2. A reference is assumed to refer to something (there is no null reference)

   A reference that "refers to nothing" (equivalent to the NULL pointer) can be created, but this is not as easy as creating a NULL pointer. Because of this the check of the reference for NULL can be omitted.

However, none of these advantages carry over directly to managed languages, so I don't see the relevance of that in the context of your discussion topic.

Answer (score 3):

In general speak, references make it possible to refer to the same object from different places.

A 'Pointer' is the name of a mechanism to implement references.  C++, Pascal, C... have pointers, C++ offers another mechanism (with slightly other use cases) called 'Reference', but essentially these are all implementations of the general referencing concept.

So there is no reason why references are by definition faster/slower than pointers.

The real difference is in using a JIT or a classic 'up front' compiler: the JIT can data take into account that aren't available for the up front compiler.  It has nothing to do with the implementation of the concept 'reference'.

Answer (score 1):

Other answers are right.

I would only add that any optimization won't make a hoot of difference unless it is in code where the program counter actually spends much time, like in tight loops that don't contain function calls (such as comparing strings).

Answer (score 0):

An object reference in a managed framework is very different from a passed reference in C++.  To understand what makes them special, imagine how the following scenario would be handled, at the machine level, without garbage-collected object references: Method "Foo" returns a string, which is stored into various collections and passed to different pieces of code.  Once nothing needs the string any more, it should be possible to reclaim all memory used in storing it, but it's unclear what piece of code will be the last one to use the string.

In a non-GC system, every collection either needs to have its own copy of the string, or else needs to hold something containing a pointer to a shared object which holds the characters in the string.  In the latter situation, the shared object needs to somehow know when the last pointer to it gets eliminated.  There are a variety of ways this can be handled, but an essential common aspect of all of them is that shared objects need to be notified when pointers to them are copied or destroyed.  Such notification requires work.

In a GC system by contrast, programs are decorated with metadata to say which registers or parts of a stack frame will be used at any given time to hold rooted object references.  When a garbage collection cycle occurs, the garbage collector will have to parse this data, identify and preserve all live objects, and nuke everything else.  At all other times, however, the processor can copy, replace, shuffle, or destroy references in any pattern or sequence it likes, without having to notify any of the objects involved.  Note that when using pointer-use notifications in a multi-processor system, if different threads might copy or destroy references to the same object, synchronization code will be required to make the necessary notification thread-safe.  By contrast, in a GC system, each processor may change reference variables at any time without having to synchronize its actions with any other processor.